# Jmockit How to match 'any' parameter type for Class<T> clazz

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit, expectations

Using jmockit, i am creating new expectation

```
    new Expectations(){{
        ConfigurationService.get(anyString,****);
    }};
```

of static method

```
public static <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) {
```

How to match 'any' parameter type for Class clazz ?

Comment: Did you try the `any` matcher?